# Jquery selector all cells in table except

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to find the correct selector to be able to change the background to blue if any Hello cell is clicked, but not if Goodbye is clicked.  Adding a class to the Hello cells is a possible option, but not preferred.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myTable td').click(function() {
    $('#myTable').addClass('unfocused');
  });
});
```

```css
.unfocused {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable'>

  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <table id='otherTable'>
        <tr>
          <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

I have tried:

```
 $('#myTable td').not('#otherTable td').click(....
 $('#myTable td').not('#otherTable').click(....
```

and those dont work.

attached a fiddle.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wqxeuw9/1/)

Comment: Do I understand correctly? You want to select all `<th>` without thoes that have `#otherTable`? If not, you need to extend it to some `if's` :/

Comment: All <th>s that are not in #otherTable

Comment: Totally unrelated question: why would you put a `table` inside a `th`?

Comment: should be td.  was just typing fast and not paying attention.

Comment: Could you pay attention and revise the question, with the correct markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it, I think you are loooking for something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/smqdx20x/

```
$('#myTable th').not($('th > table#otherTable').parent()).not('table#otherTable th')
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is what you need. See demo below

**Two options are available.**

Since you're checking the text content of `<th>` to perform a specific action, then you can use jQuery `.text()` to get the content of the `<th>`.

[Read more about jQuery .text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

You'll also need JavaScript `this` to refer to the currently clicked `<th>`.

[Read more about this keyword at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

**Option 1**

This option keeps adding `.unfocused` class to all `<th>` when clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('th').click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Hello") {
      $(this).addClass('unfocused');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.unfocused {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <table id='otherTable'>
        <tr>
          <th>Goodbye</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Option 2**

This option removes `.unfocused` class from all `<th>` before adding `.unfocused` class to the currently clicked `<th>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('th').click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "Hello") {
      $('th').removeClass('unfocused');
      $(this).addClass('unfocused');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.unfocused {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <table id='otherTable'>
        <tr>
          <th>Goodbye</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are giving background to parent. So this solution may be useful to you.

[First Way](https://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/2wqxeuw9/2/)

```
$('#myTable th').click(function() {
    $('#myTable').addClass('unfocused');
    $('#otherTable').addClass('white');
});
```

[Second Way](https://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/2wqxeuw9/3/)

```
$('#myTable th').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('unfocused');
    $(this).parent().siblings().not(".check").addClass('unfocused');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myTable th:contains(Hello)').click(function() {
    $('#myTable').addClass('unfocused');
  });
});
```

```css
.unfocused {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Goodbye</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```